# Not getting a response from a chai .post request in mocha javascript node.js unit test framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing a web site route which adds a medical device to a database.  This is a really simple form and only includes 4 fields: title, description, category, and condition.  Here is my mocha / chai unit test code:

```
it('/items/create POST No Errors', function(done){
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/items/create')
        .field('title','XRay Machine')
        .field('description','2005 Model Year')
        .field('category','Hospital Equipment')
        .field('condition','Used')
        // do I need a send here?????
        .end(function(err, res){
            console.log(res); // get nothing from this
            expect(err).to.be.null;
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
});
```

First, the node.js server is working fine.  I can connect with a browser, fill out the form, click the submit button, and the medical item is successfully created and saved in the database.  Second, the above test code also successfully creates and saves an medical item in the database; however, it never receives a response and the test times out.  Why is the test timing out?  Why doesn't it receive a response?  Do I have to "click the save button" on the form by using a .send command?  If yes, how do I determine what to "send"?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was no formal response to the /items/create route; but rather, this route created a redirect.  That's why a response was never received and the test timed out.  One of my peeps on the team I'm working on figured it out.